# Consume remote CSV and convert to model for view in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, csv

I have a CSV file on a remote server that is accessible via a URL such as: http://mydomain.com/test.csv. It is simply records of a key/value pair. In my controller, how would I consume that CSV file and pass to the view as a model? I am a little new to MVC3 so I would appreciate any help.

Here is a sample of my CSV:

```
key,value
Key1,ValueA
Key2,ValueB
Key3,ValueC
Key4,ValueD
```

Comment: Which part you need help? Download the file? Parse the CSV? Use it as a model?

Comment: Do you think about parsing csv in every request? You could think about a caching strategy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't call it from the controller. I would delegate that logic to a service, using interface-driven development.

[A quick google](http://tinyurl.com/3sef9fr) yields plenty of results for a CSV parser. So it's just a matter of constructing a HTTP request, parsing the CSV and then mapping it to a ViewModel.

So your controller could look like this:

```
    private ICsvParsingService _csvParsingService; // tip: use DI to inject the concrete in ctor.

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Csv()
    {
       var csv = _csvParsingService.Parse("http://mydomain.com/test.csv");
       var model = Mapper.Map<SomeCsvType,YourModel>(csv); // AutoMapper. Or you could do L-R.
       return View(model);
    }
```

This way, if you decide to use a different CSV parser (or roll your own), your Controller need not change. And you can re-use this service across your application.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like such a basic question.  Something like this should get you started.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string csvContents = client.DownloadString(UrlAsString);
string[] csvLines = csvContents.Split(new string[] {"\n", "\r\n"},
                                      StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); 
SomeModel model = new SomeModel()
model.KeyValuePairs = csvLines.Select(x => x.Contains(","))
                          .Select(x => new KeyValuePair(x.Split(",")[0],
                                                        x.Split(",")[1]);


public class SomeModel()
{
  public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair> KeyValuePairs { get; set; }
}

public class KeyValuePair()
{
   public KeyValuePair() { }
   public KeyValuePair(string Key, string Value) 
   { 
     this.Key = Key;
     this.Value = Value;
   }
   public string Key { get; set; }
   public string Value { get; set; }
}
```